# How to extract data from returned facebook graph api hash

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, titanium-alloy

I have successfully logged into my android titanium alloy app. I have requested some data via the facebook graph api and on success i bring up an alert to display returned data.

```
if (e.success) {
        alert(e.result);
    }
```

the returned data is in this format,

```
{"id":"123456789","name":"personsname"}
```

I am trying to extract id data like this

```
alert(e.result["id"]);
```

but this is not working as the alert returns nothing. Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a string containing JSON data.

To use it as an object, you need to parse it first:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(e.result);
alert(obj.id);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, how did you know that it was a string containing JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
alert(e.result.id);
```

Should work, and I can not say why your code does not work. The both approaches are identical.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but it still does not recover the data. SLaks answer was the one that worked.